# Kafka Streams | Aggregation of Joined stream

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I want to join two topic streams (left join) and do a window-based aggregation over the joined stream. However, the aggregation is counting some of the messages twice as during join some messages are emitted twice depending on the delay in the right topic. 
Following is the code for the POC.

```
        StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
        KStream<Long, BidMessage> bidStream = builder.stream("bid", Consumed.with(new LongSerde(), new BidMessageSerde()).withTimestampExtractor(new BidMessageTimestampExtractor()));
        KStream<Long, ClickMessage> clickStream = builder.stream("click", Consumed.with(new LongSerde(), new ClickMessageSerde()).withTimestampExtractor(new ClickMessageTimestampExtractor()));

        KStream<String, BidMessage> newBidStream = bidStream.selectKey((key, value) -> value.getRequestId());
        KStream<String, CLickMessage> newClickStream = impStream.selectKey((key, value) -> value.getRequestId());

        KStream<String, BidMergedMessage> result = newBidStream.leftJoin(newImpStream,
                getValueJoiner(),
                JoinWindows.of(Duration.ofSeconds(30)).grace(Duration.ofSeconds(0)),
                Joined.with(Serdes.String(), new BidMessageSerde(), new ClickMessageSerde()));

        result.groupBy((key, value) -> "" + value.getClientId(), Grouped.with(Serdes.String(), newBidMergedSerde()))
                .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofSeconds(30)).grace(Duration.ofSeconds(40)))
                .aggregate(() -> new AggResult(0, 0), (key, value, aggregate) -> {
                    if (value.getClickId() != null) {
                        aggregate.clicks_++;
                    }
                    aggregate.bids_++;
                    return aggregate;
                }, Materialized.with(Serdes.String(),new AggResultJsonSerde()))
                .suppress(Suppressed.untilWindowCloses(Suppressed.BufferConfig.unbounded()))
                .toStream()
                .foreach((key, value) -> {
                    logger.info("{}-{}, clientId : {}, Value: {}", new Date(key.window().start()), new Date(key.window().end()),key.key(), value);
                });

        final KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), props);
        streams.start();
```

Can it be fixed to avoid the duplicates due to join?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I'm following your requirements thoroughly, but it seems the problem is you want to count bids ***only*** if there wasn't a merge with the RHS or if the join is successful.  But due to some slowness in the RHS topic, you occasionally get two results first no-merged followed by a merge later when the RHS record arrives.

You could add a `TransformValues` operator on the `result` `KStream` and use a statestore to keep track of the records coming in.  When you have a duplicate that arrives from a successful join, you can look in the statestore and remove the record with the null RHS if it exists, then forward the correct join result.

To forward the records that never resulted in a successful join, you can consider using `punctuate()` to periodically go through the store and emit records that don't have a match and have been in the statestore beyond a time you feel a join should have occurred.

This [tutorial](https://kafka-tutorials.confluent.io/finding-distinct-events/kstreams.html) from Kafka Tutorials may server as a guide as well.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two options.

1. The first thing to try would be to add a `filter` to the `KStream<String, BidMergedMessage> result` stream.  I'm assuming that you can tell from the object returned from the `ValueJoiner` that the RHS value is null.
2. Use an inner-join  `newBidStream.join(newImpStream...`

-Bill

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I need both kind of bid messages, the ones which get merged with click and the ones which don't ever get merged.